# C# generic - Can I refer to an implement of an interface inside it?

Tags: c#, generics

I have some code like this:

```
public interface Base<TImpl, T1> 
  where TImpl : Base<TImpl, T1> 
{
  public T1 Build(TImpl arg);
}

public class Impl1 : Base<Impl1, int>
{
  public int Value { get; set; }

  public int Build(Impl1 arg)
  {
     return arg.Value;
  }
}

public class Impl2 : Base<Impl2, string>
{
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public string Build(Impl2 arg)
  {
     return arg.Value;
  }
}
```

The `TImpl` generic argument seems quite ugly to me. Do I have a chance to safely remove the `TImpl` part, or remove `T1, T2...` and can write something like `public TImpl.C1 Method(TImpl arg);`?

Comment: This is the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, however, I am personally finding this question a little unclear, what is it you are actually trying to achieve here, what is your use case? Also the lack of standard C# standard naming conversions makes this a little hard to read, not to mention the would be compiler errors

Comment: Wow, I am full of typos tonight. I best give up while I'm ahead

Comment: I made the question more clearly and then I find I just don't need to pass in the instance as an argument by simply use `this`.

Comment: _" Do I have a chance to safely remove the ...."_ - it depends on what you want to do with `Impl1`, `Impl2`, ... and `Base` interface next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be an example of [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It does not make much sense when there is only one implementing class.

The point of this pattern is to make sure that the argument to `Impl.Method` is also `Impl`. There would not be any simple way to avoid this pattern while supplying the same level of type-safety.

Eric Lippert, one of the architects behind C#, has an [article on the subject](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/) where he points out that while the pattern have some potential uses, it also have problems (thanks to Matthew Watson for pointing it out). And conclude with:

> My advice is to think very hard before you implement this sort of curious pattern in C#; do the benefits to the customer really outweigh the costs associated with the mental burden you’re placing on the code maintainers?

You could also always ignore type-safety and just take and return objects, but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Made edits to the question and found I'm just stupid. Still accept for the pattern information.

Comment: Some interesting discussion from Eric Lippert about CRTP: https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/ To summarise: He doesn't like it (and he explains why in the article I linked)